# Can you have an `<li>` in a autonomous custom element with the parent `<ul>` not in the same ShadowDOM?

Tags: accessibility, web-component

My understanding used to be that a list item `<li>` tag had to be the direct child of a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` tag.

But I've been using web components and autonomous custom elements recently. And I've read that for autonomous custom elements, the content model is transparent. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts

I want to have an autonomous custom element `<my-list>` which has a `<ul>` in its shadowDOM (or one of the other valid parents, such as `ol` and `menu`), and a second autonomous custom element `<my-list-item>` with an `<li>` in its shadowDOM. (See "the example" below.)

Why? A few reasons:

- css styling scoped to the shadowDOM
- additional event handlers
- some use cases might have more going on, like each `<li>` containing shadowDOM children besides just the `<slot>`
- I'm using Lit 3, so its natural to write a web component

Is something like this example below valid or invalid, according to the HTML 5 spec, and according to accessibility guidelines?

Note: I'm using the `<template shadowrootmode="open">` (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#shadowrootmode ) to make my example more self contained. In my real code, I'm using the Lit framework, which creates the shadowDOM programmatically.

The example:

```html
<my-list role="presentation">
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <ul>
      <slot />
    </ul>
  </template>

  <my-list-item role="presentation">
    <template shadowrootmode="open">
      <li>
        <slot />
      </li>
    </template>

    My text here
  </my-list-item>
</my-list>
```

Another reasons I think this might be valid is that I see that axe-core has a unit test that looks similar:

https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/develop/test/checks/lists/only-listitems.js#L224-L232

```js
    it('should return false in a shadow DOM pass', () => {
      const node = document.createElement('div');
      node.innerHTML = '<li>My list item </li>';
      const shadow = node.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      shadow.innerHTML = '<ul><slot></slot></ul>';

      const checkArgs = checkSetup(node, 'ul');
      assert.isFalse(checkEvaluate.apply(checkContext, checkArgs));
    });
```

But it looks like that is a specific mode / option in axe-core and not the default behavior?

Comment: "*Is something like this valid or invalid*" Like what, exactly? Are you trying to use `li` except treat it like a custom element? If so, why not just use a custom element instead of `li`, which is _not_ a custom element? The bounty description you shared does not seem to line up with what you're asking in the question body.

Comment: As for valid, no it probably would not be valid, but that doesn't mean it won't necessarily _work_; if browsers parse it in a way that works, then it'll work. You just won't be eligible for that nice 'valid HTML' feeling. Regarding accessibility guidelines, you'd need to specify which ones. Most probably don't touch on this beyond "markup needs to be valid per the WHATWG specification"--specifically you need to focus on a practical concern, e.g. compatibility with screen readers or something else.

Comment: @TylerH I edited the question to hopefully better explain. "like this" was meant to refer to the `<my-list>` code example, and to the title of the question "Can you have an `<li>` in a autonomous custom element with the parent `<ul>` not in the same ShadowDOM?" I want two components, a list and a list item. I added some reasons I want to do this. I'm not trying to use an `li` as a custom component. I am trying to have a custom component with a shadowDOM of `<li><slot /></li>`.

Comment: @TylerH For "why not just use a custom element instead of `li`", I think what you're asking is, why bother with an `li` in the shadowDOM, why not use elementInternals to put `role="list-item"` on `<my-list-item>`? The thing is, it's been emphasized to me, over many, many years, that developers should strongly prefer to use semantic elements like `li` over generic elements like `<div role="list-item">`. "The best ARIA is no ARIA." In addition, I've been using React for a while and so that likely also influences how I approach writing a component. (But React components don't exist in the DOM.)

Comment: "*developers should strongly prefer to use semantic elements like li over generic elements like <div role="list-item">*" Understandable, but if you're concerned about semantic elements and validity, why not insert a `<ul>` around the `<li>`?

Comment: That being said, there's nothing special about `<ul>`s that makes them more fit as containers for list-items; they're essentially just block elements with some margin and padding. If you need the behavior to be identical, you can apply that margin and padding to the template wrapper... as I said above, it won't be "valid", but browsers still parse it just fine. For a div wrapper you just need to make sure you apply list-item styles to the `<li>` children to get them to behave like list-items: https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/v9k8g3wm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **theory**, whatever you have said makes sense. It means following things are true:

- Custom elements have [**transparent**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent) content model as per specification.
- As per specification, when transparent elements are nested in each other, the process has to be applied iteratively.

So, it means that you should be allowed to create completely custom lists. So, this should work:

```html
<script>
  class MyList extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .innerHTML = `
        <ul aria-label="Custom List">
          <slot></slot>
        </ul>`;
    }
  }
  class MyListItem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .innerHTML = `<li><slot></slot></li>`;
    }
    connectedCallback(){
      console.log(this.parentNode.nodeName);
    }
  }
  customElements.define('my-list', MyList);
  customElements.define('my-list-item', MyListItem);
</script>

<my-list aria-label="Custom Wrapper">
  <my-list-item>Item 1</my-list-item>
  <my-list-item>Item 2</my-list-item>
</my-list>
```

In this case, the `<ul>` lives a different shadow root than those of `<li>` elements. For this above definition, the browser ends up generating the following accessibility tree (from the Chrome browser):

[image: Accessibility Tree]

So, as per specs, the browser is properly generating the accessibility tree which is was most of the tools should see. My best guess is that `axe-core` is relying on the same specs for this given test. But there in practice, things are different.

- Many assistive have custom parser which break and/or make assumption about the HTML structure (ShadowRoot is a common hindrance)
- Even the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) doesn't recognize the custom elements.
- Although, the custom elements spec officially consider custom elements with transparent content model, the specs for [`<ul>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) and `<ol>` still explicitly restrict them to have only `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>`. (This should be addressed in future).

So, as per spec, you are good to have custom list elements within your custom list in a completely different Shadow DOM, however in practice, the accessibility will still take a hit. If possible, better to rely on classical `ul > li` or `ol > li` hierarchy.